# Cron Job stops working on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, production-environment, cron-task

I have a cron job that runs as expected on development, but stops working on production:

models/user.rb

```
def self.recalculate_age
  User.all.each do |user|
    user.recalculate
  end
end

def recalculate
  self.age = self.age + 1.37
  self.save!
end
```

config/schedule.rb

```
every 1.day, :at => '12:00 am' do
  runner "User.recalculate_age", :environment => 'development'
end
```

I forgot the terminal command that I used to start up the cron job on development, but I'm pretty sure it would be different in production anyway, right?

Also, would I change `:environment => 'development'` to `:environment => 'production'`?

Answer (score 0):

If I am right and you are using whenever gem than you should start your cron jobs on production by typing in console:

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

And of course you should change your environment to production if you want it to run on production.
To see what cron tasks are running right now you can use:

```
crontab -l
```

Answer (score 0):

The [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem will default to production so just remove the `:environment` option within your `schedule.rb` file and you should be good to go within your production environment.

In development, use the `--set` option to set the environment. Example

```
whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'
```